# Como reducir el tiempo de carga entre videos

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual tiene que cargar de forma aleatoria varios videos y audios y posterior mente reproducir, esto lo hace bien y todo, el problema es el momento de carga entre video. Cuando se termina de reproducir un video este se muestra el fondo blanco de la pagina, lo cual no es aceptable, la idea es tratar de quitar ese espacio que se forma entre la carga del video A y el video B

Mas o menos esto es lo que se ve:

Este es el espacio que nota al momento de cambiar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues mas o menos asi es como se nota eso.
La forma en como cargo la lista de reproducción es mediante ajax que me la trae desde una función php, esa lista la almaceno en otra en javascript y a medida que va reproduciendo y va terminando aumenta una posición en el vector y así me obtiene la nueva ruta.
La idea es tratar de que no aparezca eso, aquí el codigo js que utilizo.

De esta forma obtengo la lista de reproducción:

```
function getVideo() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:500/proyecto/admin/video/getListVideoRep", function (vjson) {
    video = vjson;
   });
}
```

De esta forma es que logro reproducir los videos:

```
function playVideo(id) {
   var long = video.video;
   if (id >= long.length) {
      getVideo();
   }
   else {        
      $('#index-video').attr('src', video.video[id].R);
      rep_video.play();
      continuarVideo(id);
   }
 }
```

Esta es la función que me permite continuar con la reproducción:

```
function continuarVideo(id) {
    rep_video.onended = function () {
       playVideo(parseInt(id) + 1);
    }
}
```

Alguien me podría asesorar en como solucionar esto.